# is there any way to left join the select result in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this query to left join the result of my query:

```
select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') as dt,count(*)
from action_record a
where user_id = 16459
and action_type = 1
group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')

left JOIN 

select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') as dt,max(login_count) as login_count
from report_user b
where user_id = 16459
group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')

on a.dt = b.dt
```

but it shows error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left JOIN 
select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') as' at line 6
```

what should I to fix this problem?

Comment: Consider storing `created_time/1000` into `DATETIME(3)` or `TIMESTAMP(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect mix of operators in the wrong order, specifically your `LEFT JOIN` operator can't come after the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` operators. (Normally what you're trying to achieve would be easy with CTEs but your version of MySQL doesn't have CTEs yet.)

Re-writing the query with sub-queries like this is how you can achieve your goals:

```
SELECT a.dt, a.groupCount, b.login_count
FROM
(
    select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') as dt,count(*) as groupCount
    from action_record a
    where user_id = 16459
        and action_type = 1
    group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')
) a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') as dt,max(login_count) as login_count
    from report_user b
    where user_id = 16459
    group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')
) b
ON a.dt = b.dt
```

Comment: And have `INDEX(user_id, action_type)` for `action_record` and `INDEX(user_id, statistic_time)` for `report_user`.